# Java Heap Dump from Remote Machine

Tags: jconsole

I have a remote server that runs a Web application on the JVM. I can ssh into the remote server after which I tried to use jmap to take a heap dump. But unfortunately jmap seems not to be available on the remote machine as it uses OpenJDK!

I then thought I could use JConsole from my local machine, but how could I use it to get the heap dump for a Java process that runs remote? I have the remote PID. Can I use the ssh port to first make a connection to the remote machine using JConsole?